# Johansen Test - What is a lag?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, cointegration, lags

I am new to the Johansen Test, have been using the ADF test but due to its limitations I am trying to switch over. I have taken data (1 hour bars) for 4 symbols and passed it through this function [link](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/raw/88477497/) the results are bellow. Also is a chart of the data plotted. To plot I took the eigenvectors results for $r = 0$ and multiplied it by the symbol value. The reason the chart is Red/Blue is because red is the data I tested on and blue is the data I did not pass into the test.  Now the questions are:

1. is my logic in how I have done this correct?
2. when i call the function `coint_johansen(df, 0,1)` df being the data, but there is also a 0 and 1, which is classified as followed.

> We then call the coint_johansen function by passing the data frame storing the time series data (df), 0 and 1 as its three arguments. The second term in the arguments represents the order of null hypothesis, a value of 0 implies that it is a constant term, there is no time trend in the polynomial. The third term specifies the number of lagged difference terms used when computing the estimator, here we use a single lagged difference term.

What is the best way to determine the number of lags?  When i search I keep running into something called a VAR model, could someone reference me a none PHD version of this? Or some other simple explanation/example.  When I change the lags to 11 I get a totally different plot path (charted bellow) and obviously this is far more enticing.

```
--> Trace Statistics
variable statistic Crit-90% Crit-95%  Crit-99%
r = 0    51.9614 44.4929 47.8545 54.6815
r = 1    19.7861 27.0669 29.7961 35.4628
r = 2    5.4724 13.4294 15.4943 19.9349
r = 3    1.1118 2.7055 3.8415 6.6349
--> Eigen Statistics
variable statistic Crit-90% Crit-95%  Crit-99%
r = 0    32.1752 25.1236 27.5858 32.7172
r = 1    14.3137 18.8928 21.1314 25.865
r = 2    4.3606 12.2971 14.2639 18.52
r = 3    1.1118 2.7055 3.8415 6.6349
eigenvectors:
 [[  1.64822424e-01  -3.02248875e-01  -4.98243215e-02   4.94890919e-04]
 [ -5.56290345e-01   6.57055787e-02  -5.19231801e-02   4.65781352e-02]
 [  1.27230050e-02  -8.17785528e-03   3.41343963e-02  -6.60752179e-02]
 [  1.59919621e-01   1.24338818e-01   1.52753375e-01   2.07462450e-02]]
```

eigenvalues:
     [ 0.01011763  0.00451371  0.00137726  0.00035132]

[image]
[image]

---

just after posting this, i found this snippet of code.  Would this be the best way to test statistically for the best number of lags:

I presume the question still is what is and how does a lag effect the johansen_test results.  do we just choose the lowest AIC?  or is there some other common method?

```
var_mod = VAR(df0)
var_mod.select_order(15)

# check autocorrelation of residuals 
res_df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(1,16), columns=df0.columns)

for k in range(1,16):
    var_res = var_mod.fit(k)
    pvals = []
    for c in df0.columns:
        stat, pval = acorr_ljungbox(var_res.resid[c],8)
        res_df.ix[k][c] = round(pval[-1],3)

print ("Residuals auto-corr test.. Ljung-Box test p-values")
print(res_df)
```

which gives an output of something like the following in the example above.

```
                  VAR Order Selection                  
======================================================
            aic          bic          fpe         hqic
------------------------------------------------------
0         2.834        2.846        17.02        2.839
1        -15.26       -15.20    2.366e-07       -15.23
2        -15.48      -15.37*    1.889e-07      -15.44*
3       -15.49*       -15.33   1.883e-07*       -15.43
4        -15.48       -15.27    1.901e-07       -15.40
5        -15.47       -15.22    1.908e-07       -15.38
6        -15.47       -15.17    1.912e-07       -15.36
7        -15.47       -15.12    1.918e-07       -15.34
8        -15.46       -15.06    1.933e-07       -15.31
9        -15.45       -15.00    1.949e-07       -15.29
10       -15.44       -14.94    1.971e-07       -15.26
11       -15.44       -14.89    1.978e-07       -15.24
12       -15.43       -14.83    1.999e-07       -15.21
13       -15.42       -14.78    2.010e-07       -15.18
14       -15.42       -14.73    2.014e-07       -15.16
15       -15.42       -14.68    2.013e-07       -15.15
======================================================
* Minimum

Residuals auto-corr test.. Ljung-Box test p-values
     sys0   sys1   sys2   sys3
1   0.706  0.844    0.7  0.088
2   0.953   0.89  0.823  0.162
3   0.955   0.85  0.873  0.179
4   0.966  0.971  0.922   0.18
5   0.968  0.953  0.918  0.461
6   0.981  0.971  0.993  0.508
7   0.997   0.98  0.998  0.799
8       1  0.993  0.998  0.998
9       1      1      1      1
10      1      1      1      1
11      1      1      1      1
12      1      1      1      1
13      1      1      1      1
14      1      1      1      1
15      1      1      1      1
```